# Create in-memory only gzip

Tags: ruby, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to gzip a file in ruby without having to write it to disk first. Currently I only know how to make it work by using `Zlib::GzipWriter`, but I'm really hoping that I can avoid that and keep it in-memory only.

I've tried this, with no success:

```
def self.make_gzip(data)
  gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(StringIO.new)
  gz << data
  string = gz.close.string
  StringIO.new(string, 'rb').read
end
```

Here is what happens when I test it out:

```
# Files
normal = File.new('chunk0.nbt')
gzipped = File.new('chunk0.nbt.gz')


# Try to create gzip in program
make_gzip normal
=> "\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\x8AJhS\u0000\u0003S\xB6q\xCB\xCCI\xB52\xA8000OK1L\xB2441J5\xB5\xB0\u0003\u0000\u0000\xB9\x91\xDD\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000"

# Read from a gzip created with the gzip command
reader = Zlib::GzipReader.open gzipped
reader.read
"\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\xED]\xDBn\xDC\xC8\u0011%\x97N\xB82<\x9E\x89\xFF!\xFF!\xC9\xD6dFp\x80\u0005\xB2y\r\"\xEC\n\x89\xB0\xC6\xDAX+A./\xF94\xBF\u0006\xF1\x83>`\u0005\xCC\u000F\xC4\xF0\u000F.............(for 10,000 columns)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What do you mean by *with no success*? BTW, the last line is redundant. You can just return `gz.close.string`.

Comment: Well, it returns data, but it's not correct. Here is some output from when I create the gzip in the program, and then when I read from a real gzip: http://pastebin.com/RBNvx6r4

Comment: the site gets blocked here, you should better update your post directly. It may help others know what your problem is.

Comment: Ok, post has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually gzipping `normal.to_s`(which is something like `"#<File:0x007f53c9b55b48>"`) in the following code.

```
# Files
normal = File.new('chunk0.nbt')

# Try to create gzip in program
make_gzip normal
```

You should read the content of the file, and `make_gzip` on the content:

```
make_gzip normal.read
```

As I commented, the `make_gzip` can be updated:

```
def self.make_gzip(data)
  gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(StringIO.new)
  gz << data
  gz.close.string
end
```